# Calculate difference between 2 measured points of depth of different manholes in a road

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have a question regarding creating relations between some information in the Qgis-system.
The situation where I would like to make relationships is as following.

I have several “manholes” which are connected which each other via tubes in a road.
I need to know if the depth of the exit hole from “manhole A” which goes to the entrance of “manhole B” which have a other depth are in line. I mean that the water flows from manhole A to manhole B.
I want to see on the figures if the water flows down wards and not up wards and that each time with the next manholes. (Comparing between next following ones)

Comment: Are the manholes numbered consistently in order, or they appear in the attribute table in order? If not, how do you determine the sequence?

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you correctly, you have start and end z value for every pipe line (or tube)(The z values comes from manhole entrance).
So you need the organize your datas like the example table (pipe base).

[image]

After that you can create 2 different rule-based symbology for 2 different situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your feedback. I will give it a try, many thanks already